# Perimeter of Right-Angled Triangle in Terms of its Similar Triangles

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

This exercise was given as preparation for my upcoming midterm and I've been struggling with it enormously. The problems states;

The altitude from the right angle of a right angled triangle divides it into two triangles of perimeters p and q. Compute in terms of p and q the perimeter of the triangle ABC.

I'm aware that within my triangle ABC there are three similar triangles and there are various proportions of side length that can be found, but yet after a weekend of work I cannot find the perimeter of ABC depending only on p and q.  Any guidance or advice will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two triangles
are similar to
the original triangle.

Let $t$ be the original triangle.

The perimeter of $t$
is the sums of
the areas of $p$ and $q$
minus twice the altitude
which is common to both.
If the altitude is $h$,
then,
with "per" meaning "perimeter",
$per(p)+per(q)-2h
=per(t)
$.

If the sides of the
original triangle are
$a, b, c$,
then
$area(t) = ab/2
=ch/2$.

Therefore
$h = ab/c$.

Therefore
$per(t)
=per(p)+per(q)-2ab/c
=per(p)+per(q)-2ab/\sqrt{a^2+b^2}
$.

From the similar triangles
$\dfrac{per(p)}{a}
=\dfrac{per(q)}{b}
=\dfrac{per(t)}{c}
$,
so
$a=\dfrac{c\,per(p)}{per(t)}$
and
$b=\dfrac{c\,per(q)}{per(t)}$.

Multiplying,
$ab
=\dfrac{c^2\,per(p)per(q)}{per^2(t)}
$
so that
$h
=ab/c
=\dfrac{c\,per(p)per(q)}{per^2(t)}
$.

I don't see
how to get an expression
for $per(t)$
involving only
$per(p)$ and $per(q)$,
so I'll leave it at this.

Maybe the areas come in,
and the fact that
they are proportional
to the squares of the sides
would be of use.

Comment: Thanks actually, this equality combined with the ones I had helped solve the problem. What a relief!