# Perimeter of a Right-angled Triangle divided in Two

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

The altitude from the right angle of a right-angled triangle $ABC$ divides it into two triangles of perimeters $p$ and $q$. Compute, in the terms of $p$ and $q$, the perimeter of the triangle $ABC$.

[image]

I got that $p+q=Perimeter(ABC) + 2|AD|$, but I got lost

Any hints?

Thanks

Comment: Is this possible?  With a little effort we get that the total perimeter is $p+q-2\frac {AB\times AC}{BC}$ but beyond that...

Comment: $2 |AD|$, actually.

Comment: Note:  [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1971846/perimeter-of-right-angled-triangle-in-terms-of-its-similar-triangles) appeared yesterday...the posted solution there doesn't solve it either.

Comment: @lulu: But the last sentence of that solution does allude to the right approach.

Comment: @BrianTung  Ha!  Quite right.  Interesting...my initial thought was that this wasn't doable.

Comment: @lulu: It is, and the answer is charming, I think.  I like the question enough to +1 it.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**.  Use the fact that $\triangle ABC, \triangle DBA, \triangle DAC$ are all similar.

**Further Hint, Rot13'd**.  Jung ner gurve nernf?  (Use http://www.rot13.com/ to decode.)